# File IO: Line by Line Comparison In C, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, file-io, io, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm really stuck on this problem. I'm trying to write a program in C that will take a file, and check to see if every line is in alphabetical order.

So the text file

> apple
>
> banana
>
> grape
>
> grape
>
> orange

The program would print to stdout "Lines are in order". If the lines are out of order it would print say the lines are out of order and print the first pair of lines where that occurs.

The main thing I'm having trouble with is just debugging, I keep getting a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. I don't think that theres an instance where I'm trying to dereference a null pointer and I don't think there's an instance where I try to assign something with more memory than a pointer can handle so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Below is my code, I'm really new to C so if there is anything obvious or fundamental flaws in my code I'd really appreciate being told so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(char* argv[],int argc){
  char* fileN = argv[1];
  FILE* file = fopen(fileN,"r");
  if (file == NULL){
    perror("Error: Couldn't open file");
    exit(1);
  }else{
    char *line = malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    fgets(line,101,file);
    char *comp = malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    while(line){
      fgets(comp,101,file);
      if (comp){
          if(strcmp(line,comp) > 0){
               printf("Lines out of order\n");
               printf("%s\n",line);
               printf("%s\n",comp);
               free(line);
               free(comp);
               fclose(file);
               exit(1);
          } 
      }
      line = comp;
    }   
    printf("Lines are ordered\n");
    free(line);
    free(comp);
    fclose(file);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple problems. For example your comparison of the pointers will *never* be false (unless the initial `malloc` calls failed). Or that you compare the contents of a buffer with itself. Or attempting to free the same memory twice. I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and step through the program in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: If your lines are that small, skip the `malloc` and `free` memory allocation stuff and just use `char line[101], comp[101];`. If the maximum length of the lines is unknown or a possibly large number, then you'd want to deal with `malloc` and friends. This will simplify your debugging somewhat as long as you don't read beyond the end of the arrays. `line = comp;` will set `line` to the same address as `comp` (if you used regular arrays, you'd get a compile error because you can't change the address of an array); you want to use `strcpy(line, comp)`. Also, `argc` and `argv` are out of order.

Comment: Your loop will always be true btw and will never reach the end of the program unless the lines are out of order. You need to use the return value of `fgets` instead to read until an error occurs or you reach the end of the file. `fgets` will only return a null pointer when either an error occurs, or when no bytes have been read and you're at the end of the file. `if (comp)` and `while (line)` both exhibit the same problem: they will always be true if `malloc` doesn't return a null pointer (else you're trying to use `fgets` with a null pointer, which will likely cause a segfault).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone, here is a version of the program that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  char* fileN = argv[1];
  FILE* file = fopen(fileN,"r");
  if (file == NULL){
    perror("Error: Couldn't open file");
    exit(1);
  }else{
    char line[101], comp[101];
    fgets(line,101,file);
    int bool = 1;
    while(line && bool){
      if (fgets(comp,101,file) != NULL){
         if(strcmp(line,comp) > 0){
           printf("Lines out of order\n");
           printf("%s",line);
           printf("%s\n",comp);
           fclose(file);
           exit(1);
         }
         strncpy(line,comp,100);
      }else{
         bool = 0;
      }
    }   
    printf("Lines are ordered\n");
    fclose(file);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

My mistakes were A) forgetting how to properly copy one string over to one another and B) not realizing that fgets would return null if it fails, that's what I needed to use to make sure my loops actually ends.

Comment: Use `fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)` and `fgets(comp, sizeof(comp), file)` rather than repeating `101` everywhere.  And `strncpy(line, comp, 100);` should use `sizeof(line)-1` rather than 100.  And maybe use `enum { MAX_LINE = 101 }; char line[MAX_LINE], comp[MAX_LINE];` so that when you want to change `101` into `4096`, you only have to change one line — the enum.  Also note that using `strncpy()` is mostly superfluous here.  The value in `comp` is null-terminated within the length of `comp`, and `line` and `comp` are the same size, so a plain `strcpy()` would be perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me, if you need comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 100

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char a[MAX_LINE];
    char b[MAX_LINE];

    FILE* fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!fd) {
        puts("Error: Couldn't open file");
        exit(1);
    }   

    fgets(a, MAX_LINE, fd);

    while(fgets(b, MAX_LINE, fd)) {

        if(strcmp(a, b) > 0) {
            puts("Lines out of order");

            printf("a = %s", a); 
            printf("b = %s", b); 

            fclose(fd);
            exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(a, b); 
    }   

    puts("Lines are ordered");

    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```